# Compiling java program with JARs and resource folder

Tags: java, compilation

I want to compile my Java program in command line. Until now, NetBeans have been doing this job for me.

My program consists of:

```
/program/
        /src/mypacket/
                     /klass1.java
                     /...
        /src/Main.java
        /resources/
                  /img1.png
                  /...
        /lib/
            /jar1.jar
            /...
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to build a proper command. My efforts resulted in sth like:

```
javac -classpath lib/*.jar src/mypacket/*.java src/Main.java
```

In result I get ~20 errors similar to:

```
src/mypacket/myclass.java:4: error: The import xyz.zyx cannot be resolved
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: all imports are from lib? aren't there libraries referenced indirectly from lib jars that you need to provide in classpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classpath should be `lib/one.jar:lib/two.jar` but your shell expands it to `lib/one.jar lib/two.jar`.

Comment: I assumed that you are using Linux, Unix or MacOs because of using slash and *. If it is not true, shout.

Comment: `dir/*.ext` works in Windows too, since at least Windows XP.  You should probably note in your answer that the path separator char in Windows is `;`.